# Implementation of Bean machine (Galton board)

Tags: graphics, dynamic, random, animation

> Bean machine  is a triangular array of pegs, Balls are dropped onto the top peg and then bounce their way down to the bottom where they are collected in little bins.Each time a ball hits one of the pegs, it bounces either left or right.

I'm trying to make a [Bean machine (Galton board)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_machine), probably like this effect. The problem now is slow to generate random paths, and the path is sometimes displayed incomplete. Is there a better way to achieve it? Or generate and plot in real time instead of generating all the lists first. Also, how to make real-time statistics and graphs below?

```
n = 10;
pts = Table[{(2 j - i)/Sqrt[3], -i}, {i, 0., n}, {j, 0, i}];

paths = Table[FoldList[ Function[{x, i}, RandomChoice@
       Select[MovingAverage[pts[[i + 1]], 2], Norm[# - x] == 2/Sqrt[3] &]], N@{0, -1}, 
 Range[2, n]], {5000}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Manipulate[
 bsf = BSplineFunction[paths[[Floor@i]], SplineDegree -> 1];
 t = FractionalPart[i];
 Graphics[{Point /@ pts, {
    Red, Dashed, Point[bsf[t]], Line@Table[bsf[t0], {t0, 0, t, 0.01}]
    }}, Axes -> True], {i, 1, Length@paths, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Updated code

```
Clear["`*"];
n = 10;
pts = Table[{(2 j - i)/Sqrt[3], -i}, {i, 0., n}, {j, 0, i}];
p2 = Mean@pts[[2]];

P = {};

Dynamic[Graphics[{Point /@ pts, {Red, Dashed, Arrow@Join[{p2}, P]}}, PlotLabel -> i]]
Dynamic[BarChart[SortBy[Tally[Round[A, 10^-9.]], First][[All, 2]]]]

A = {};
Do[
 P = {};
 pt = p2;
 Do[AppendTo[P, pt]; 
    pt = pt + {RandomChoice[{1, -1} /Sqrt[3]], -1}; 
    Pause@0.01, {n}]; AppendTo[A, P[[-1, 1]]], {i, 10^4}]
```

The animation below was created by [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/tygxktjn)
[image: Created by GeoGebra]

Comment: Do you have any code for the animation you added to your question?  Even if not Mathematica code?

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Flexible Galton Board](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FlexibleGaltonBoard/)

Comment: @Jagra That animation was created by Geogebra, https://www.geogebra.org/classic/tygxktjn

Comment: The Geogebra link gives you a good idea of the controls to include in your `Manipulate`

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[trilattice, singlePath]
trilattice[n_] := {PointSize[Medium], 
   Point[Prepend[{0, 1}] @ (Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#, -#2[[1]] + 1}] &, 
        Range[-(# + 1)/2, (# + 1)/2] & /@ Range[0, n]])]};

singlePath[length_] := Accumulate[Prepend[{0, 0}] @ 
    Thread[{RandomChoice[{1, -1}/2, length], -1}]];
```

***Examples:***

```
n = 10;
pth = singlePath @ n;

Animate[Graphics[{trilattice[n], Red, Dashed, Line[pth[[;; j]]], 
   AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[pth[[j]]]}], {j, 1, n + 1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
frames1 = Table[Graphics[{trilattice[n], Red, Dashed, Line[pth[[;; j]]], 
     AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[pth[[j]]]}], {j, n + 1}];

Export["galton1.gif", frames1, 
  AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity, "DisplayDurations" -> 1/5]
```

[image]

```
n = 10; 
SeedRandom[1];
joinedpaths = Join @@ Table[singlePath[n], 200];

histograms = Table[Histogram[Most @ 
 joinedpaths[[(n + 1) ;; (n + 1 + (n + 1) (Floor[j/(n + 1)])) ;; (n + 1), 
       1]],
   {MovingAverage[Range[-6, 6], 2]}, "Probability", 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 1 -> 25, 
    GridLines -> {None, Range[5]/10}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Dotted, 
    ImageSize -> 1 -> 30, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[-5, 5], None}}, 
    FrameStyle -> {{LineOpacity -> 0, None}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {0, 1/2}}], {j, 1, Length[joinedpaths] - 1, 1}];

lines = Table[Graphics[GraphicsComplex[joinedpaths, 
   {Red, Dashed, Line[Range[(1 + Ceiling[j - (n + 1), n + 1]), j]], 
    AbsolutePointSize[7], Point@j}]], 
  {j, 1, Length[joinedpaths] - 1, 1}];

Manipulate[Column[{
    Show[Graphics[{trilattice[n]}], lines[[j]], 
     PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, All}, FrameStyle -> Opacity[0], 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Range[-5, 5], None}}, 
     Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 1 -> 25], 
    histograms[[j]]}, 
  Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> 5], 
 {j, 1, Length[joinedpaths] - 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extended comment to resources and some suggestions on strategy...

Wolfram Demonstration Project links:

- [Galton Board](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GaltonBoard/)
- [Idealized Galton  Board](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IdealizedGaltonBoard/)
- [Dynamically Updated Probabilistic Galton Board](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DynamicallyUpdatedProbabilisticGaltonBoard/)
- [Flexible Galton Board](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FlexibleGaltonBoard/)

I'll try to get to more of an answer over the next day or so, but until then, give some thought to simplifying your approach:

Something like the following might more directly contribute to getting/displaying what you want:

```
Show[
  ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Black],
  ParametricPlot[bsf[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
  ]]
```

I think it would better correspond to what you want to show, e.g., a background against which you display the action.

I further suggest that your `Manipulate` serve you better if it contain more manipulated inputs.  These could include:

- the number of paths you want to run,
- how many steps or levels you want in the Galton Board,
- probability a bay would bounce left or right,
- ...

Lot's more about all of this in the attached links.

Again, I'll try to get to more of an answer over the next day or so.